# Обмен данными между несколькими проектами в одном solution

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Есть солюшн, в нём, естественно, проект. Есть ли возможность разнести его на несколько проектов?

К примеру: планируется вынести авторизацию в отдельный проект, и далее, в зависимости от прав, перенаправлять куда надо. Суть в том, чтобы разбить логику приложения, не смешивая всё в кучу.

Как вообще это работает в asp.net, если конечно, возможно?

```
Solution {
 - auth
 - seller
 - buyer
 - n-project
 }
```

Comment: Вы хотите просто разнести в разные проекты части кода, или вы хотите запускать отдельно сервер авторизации, отдельно еще какие то сервисы?

Comment: Это скорее всего глупая идея. Есть вариант разделить фронтенд и бэкенд, но авторизацию отдельно... Это получится как два работающих сервера. Зачем вам это?

Comment: @VladimirPaliukhovich а почему два сервера, он будет компилить две отдельные .dll для каждого проекта?

Comment: @МстиславПавлов да, отделить логику друг от друга т.к. система одна большая, но выполняет совершенно разные функции, сделать их независимыми друг от друга. Это возможно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, это возможно. Тут возможны несколько вариантов.

Во-первых, можно просто создать кучу веб-проектов, а потом создать "главный", и из "главного" кинуть референсы на остальных. Код инициализации (который global.asax.cs) во "внутренних" проектах придется преобразовать во что-то другое, что потом можно будет вызывать из главного. Может быть, тут подойдут [области](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx) из ASP.NET. А может, и не подойдут - не зря же они уже устарели.

Сложнее со статическими файлами - на этапе формирования выходного пакета вам в любом случае придется включать файлы из дочерних проектов в пакет родительского. Тут без хороших знаний MSBuild не обойтись.

А вот при отладке можно, как вариант, насоздавать виртуальных папок в настройках IIS, чтобы файлы из дочерних проектов оказались "внутри" родительского.

---

Если использовать ASP.NET Core - то все становится несколько проще, поскольку там обработка статические файлов точно так же настраивается из кода, а не из IIS. Но тут я сильно помочь не могу - поскольку сам с ASP.NET Core толком не работал.

---

Во-вторых, можно проекты сделать полностью независимыми. В таком случае проблема "слить их в один" исчезает - но появляется проблема общей авторизации (термин для гугления - SSO, single sign on). Ее можно делать через OpenID-connect (расширение oauth2), или на основе старого протокола WS-Federation. Достоинства WS-Federation - поддержка на стороне "чистого" ASP.NET, больше достоинств нет.

В качестве сервера для авторизации можно взять [`IdentityServer3`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3), чтобы на его базе построить что-нибудь свое. Или же, если речь идет об интерпрайзе - можно взять ADFS (Active Directory Federation Services). Последний вариант особенно удобен если надо интегрироваться с Active Directory.

---

Если же все что перечислено выше страшно и жутко - то можно попробовать просто по-лучше упорядочить папки в самом проекте. Как-то так:

```
Auth
  Controllers
  Content
  Views
Seller
  Controller
  Content
  Views
Buyer
  Controller
  Content
  Views
```

Для того, чтобы с таким проектом было комфортно работать, надо будет сделать свой хелпер `Url` (чтобы автоматически подставлял имя модуля в методе `Content`) - звучит страшно, но на самом деле тут все просто. Хелпер `Url` - это просто свойство в классах [`WebViewPage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.mvc.webviewpage(v=vs.118).aspx) или [`WebViewPage<>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/gg402107(v=vs.118).aspx). Если унаследоваться от них - то хелпер `Url` можно заменить на любой свой класс.

Также понадобится заменить класс [`RazorViewEngine`](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/RazorViewEngine.cs) в коллекции `ViewEngines.Engines` на свою реализацию интерфейса `IViewEngine` (да, этот вариант тоже страшный и жуткий, хоть и не настолько).

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ, будем смотреть, пробовать!)