# Роутеры в двух приложениях

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

У меня есть Solution. В нём 3 проекта: Admin,Model,Widget.
Model это class library, её не трогаем.

Admin and App это asp.net mvc приложения. При запуске решения работает только роутер у Admin. Widget роутер возвращает 404.

Как заставить работать роутеры у двух проектов сообща?

Вот структура приложения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код роутера Admin project:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace IQS
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Admin",
                url: "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Service", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Вот роутер у Widget project:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Widget
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Widget",
                url: "Widget/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Service", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new string[] { "Widget.Controllers" }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Можно наверно с помощью областей, но опыта нет.

Comment: Недавно отвечал на [похожий вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/486289/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-solution/486530). Не уверен, что ответ подходит полностью, но новый писать лень.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, можите мне скинуть как всё это получиться должно на пример, у меня не получилось)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admin и Widget у вас оформлены двумя раздельными сайтами.

При запуске по <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> студия запускает только один из них - тот, который выбран как Startup Project.

Он подсвечен в Solution Explorer - это Admin.

Т.к. практически вы запускаете только один сайт, у которого есть роут на Admin, который и работает. Widget при этом просто лежит как папка на диске, и никак не подхватывается IIS-ом.

Что вам стоит сделать:

- Оставить один проект для сайта (создать новый)
- Добавить в него две области - Admin и Widget (правой кнопкой по проекту, Add/Area)
- Добавить в каждую область по контроллеру (назвать их по-разному!)

Результат будет выглядеть примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В каждом сгенерированном контроллере будет дефолтный Action, с комментарием вида

```
public class WidgetTestController : Controller
{
    // GET: Widget/WidgetTest
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

- Сделайте новый сайт стартовым проектов - Right Click / Set as startup project.
- Запустите новый сайт по F5,
- Вбейте в url путь из комментария выше - он откроет соответствующий экшн (и скорее всего ругнется на отсутствие вида - т.е. действие отработает правильно :).